# Image processing adjusting for camera angle when measuring an object

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, camera

I'm writing an Android app that will "calculate a few things" based on a given image.

Background:

1. The image contains a human form.
2. The user will enter the height of said human form (in feet and inches.  Example 6'2")
3. The user will then indicate the location of the top of their head and the bottom of their feet.
4. Then using this information I will grab pixels per inch relative to the picture.  This all works fine.

PROBLEM:

The problem I am having is that if the user has the camera at an angle the measurements obviously won't work correctly.  In other words...if the camera is perfectly perpendicular to the ground...it's fine.  That's not a realistic expectation of a user though.

What I'd like to know how to do is how to compensate for the angle of the camera.  Is this even possible?  I'm think it might not be, but thought it would be worthy of a second opinion from those who may be better at math than I am.

Picture provides a better example:

[image]

Comment: You should be more worried about distance from the object, if what you're measuring is pixels/inch.

Comment: Photon I already know the height of the person as well as the location of to of head and bottom of feet.  I have everything I need for pixels per inch.  Bigger concern is angle of camera

Comment: Yes, but if the camera moves back, the number of pixels/inch decreases.  Opposite if it moves forward.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

[Antonio Criminisi. "Single-View Metrology: Algorithms and Applications
(Invited Paper)". In: *Pattern Recognition*. Ed. by Luc
Van Gool. Vol. 2449. Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Springer
Berlin Heidelberg, 2002, pp. 224-239.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.1441&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

For a presentation see ["A New Approach to Obtain Height Measurements from Video"](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/presentations/spie98/criminis/p0.html).

[image]

Basically

X=Hx (1)

where x is a point in your image expressed in homogeneous coordinates, X is the corresponding point in 3D world, also expressed in homogeneous coordinates, and H is a 3x3 matrix called *homography matrix*.

So:

> Algorithm 1: planar measurements.
>
> 1. Given an image of a planar surface estimate the image-to-world homography matrix H;
> 2. Repeat
>
>    (a) Select two points x1 and x2 on the image plane;
>
>    (b) Back-project each image point into the world plane via (1) to obtain the two world points X1 and X2;
>
>    (c) Compute the Euclidean distance d(X1 ; X2).

The appendix of the above mentioned paper explains how to compute H.

More details are in

A. Criminisi. *Accurate Visual Metrology from Single and Multiple Uncalibrated Images.* Distinguished Dissertation Series. Springer-Verlag London Ltd., Sep 2001. ISBN: 1852334681.